# Hover effect goes away when I go to It

Tags: html, css, hover

I have just a school project and we have to make a website. I'm pretty new to coding and that so I've been following a youtube video on how to make a drop-down menu and the hover effect keeps going away when I hover over one of my menu options. It seems to work when I open the snippet in here but not when I open it with google chrome. pls help :(

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #190061;
}

nav h4 {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 55px;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px 20px;
}

nav ul {
  float: left;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 24px 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #190061;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
}

nav ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

nav ul li ul li a {
  padding: 8px 14px;
}

nav ul li ul li a:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

nav ul li ul li {
  width: 180px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <h4>Esports Pcs</h4>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="homepage.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="pcsweoffer.html">PCs</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="pcsweoffer.html">The Low End Destroyer</a></li>
        <li><a href="pcsweoffer.html">The Mid End Ravager</a></li>
        <li><a href="pcsweoffer.html">The High End Beast</a></li>
        <li><a href="pcsweoffer.html">The Ultimate Desecrator</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: If you can't recreate it here there is not much we can help you with since we don't know what is actually *not* happening.

Comment: please open F12 and look at element tab to see what append to your css(maybe some other css override your css etc )

Comment: just guessing here...but in case that the "left side" of each menu item, that won't react on hover (will not get red and no cursor change) is the problem, set padding off *nav ul li ul* to 0. Should there be a padding, move the :hover action from <a> to <li> itself.

Comment: Welcome to Stack, would you be kind enough to lay your question out a little better for future readers please? Your title is not descriptive. The content does not explain what you would like the end result to be, you have shown your code but not explained what you would like your hover effect to be doing. I can help you do whatever you are trying to do, I am just here reviewing your question for now.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully it works for you!
I have been removed float properties and added flex properties.
Link provided [codepen](https://codepen.io/asiyafatima_12/pen/bGqvGKY)

```css
.container { position: relative; } 
nav {
width: 100%;
/*height: 60px;*/ /*Removed*/
background-color: #190061;
}
nav h4 {
  /* font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; */
  font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100; 
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 55px;
  /*float: left;*/ /*Removed */
  display:flex;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  background-color: #190061;
}
nav ul {
  /*float: left; */
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  background-color: #190061;
}

nav ul li {
  /*float: left;*/ /*Removed*/
  display: flex; /*Added*/
  justify-content: flex-start; /*Added*/
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  /*font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;*/
  font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 24px 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li ul {
  font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #190061;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
  margin-left: 67px; /*Added*/
  margin-top: 12px; /*Added*/
  list-style: none; /*Added*/
}
nav ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}

nav ul li ul li a {
  padding: 8px 8px;
  font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 14px;
}
nav ul li ul li a:hover { background-color: red; }
nav ul li ul li {
  width: 180px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<nav>
   <h4>Esports Pcs</h4>
   <ul>
 <li><a href="homepage.html">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="pcsweoffer.html">PCs</a>
   <ul>
     <li><a href="pcsweoffer.html">The Low End Destroyer</a></li>
     <li><a href="pcsweoffer.html">The Mid End Ravager</a></li>
     <li><a href="pcsweoffer.html">The High End Beast</a></li>
     <li><a href="pcsweoffer.html">The Ultimate Desecrator</a></li>
   </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Well Explained.